# How to get value from Configuration object via HostBuilder?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Started a new Console app in .NET 6 and am adding Dependency Injection.  In the code below, how can I get access to the IConfiguration object to read a value from appsettings (after calling Build?

The configuration is available within the StoreFactory service, as its injected via the constructor, but if I want to read values from appsettings within the main section of code within program.cs, how can I get at it?

**program.cs**

```
var SvcBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                 {
                     config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                     config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                     config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                     
                     if (args != null)
                     {
                         config.AddCommandLine(args);
                     }
                 })
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {
                   services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
                   .AddTransient<IStoreFactory, StoreCtxFactory>();
               });



var host = SvcBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: Do you want to get it from the `host` variable?

Comment: There is no Configuration hanging off the host variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` defines the behavior to discover the JSON configuration and expose it through the `IConfiguration` instance. From the `host` instance, you can ask the service provider for the `IConfiguration` instance and then ask it for values.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();

// Ask the service provider for the configuration abstraction.
IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

// Get values from the config given their key and their target type.
var configValueInt = config.GetValue<int>("yourKeyName");
string configValueStr = config.GetValue<string>("yourKeyName");
```

For more information read the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration).

Comment: thanks, IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(); Is what I needed

Comment: I get a IConfiguration object from this, but it only has my Windows environment variables - no appsettings info, which is what I need.